# Closest date based on 1st transaction date, Mutiple criteria in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 tables, 1 with TransictionDate_1 & 2nd table with TransictionDate_2. Both tables contain duplicate IDs.

I need to match TransictionDate_2 which nearest occurrence after TransictionDate_1.
I have tried few Array and ABS formulas but getting inconsistence result.
Below tables for more explanation.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=@IFERROR(SORTBY(_Tbl2[Transaction2_Date]/(_Tbl2[ID]=[@ID]),ABS(_Tbl2[Transaction2_Date]-[@[Transaction1_Date]])),NA())`

[image]

PS you can't use table names `TBL1` and `TBL2` since they're existing names for cell ranges (Column `TBL` row `1` and `2`), therefore I used `_Tbl1` and `_Tbl2` instead.

Or for older Excel version:
`=INDEX(_Tbl2[Transaction2_Date],MATCH(AGGREGATE(15,6,ABS(_Tbl2[Transaction2_Date]-[@[Transaction1_Date]])/(_Tbl2[ID]=[@ID]),1),ABS(_Tbl2[Transaction2_Date]-[@[Transaction1_Date]])/(_Tbl2[ID]=[@ID]),0))`

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this and let you know how i go

Comment: I added an alternative for older Excel; not sure if it requires `ctrl+shift+enter`

Comment: Thank you so much, was getting error with the first formula but the 2nd one (for older excel version) worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following formula, based on ones **`Excel Version`** may required to hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> while exiting the edit mode.

[image]

---

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Tbl_2[Transaction2_Date],
 MATCH(1,1/(([@ID]=Tbl_2[ID])*([@[Transaction1_Date]]<Tbl_2[Transaction2_Date])),-1)),"NA")
```

---

Or, if you have access to `MS365` then do the following:

[image]

---

```
=IFERROR(MIN(FILTER(Tbl_2[Transaction2_Date],(([@ID]=Tbl_2[ID])*([@[Transaction1_Date]]<Tbl_2[Transaction2_Date])))),"NA")
```

---

Comment: Thank you so much, perfect result with  CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

Comment: using if Transaction2_Date is grater than Transaction1_Date to get "Y" or "N" will work adding the formula without issue? just checking as working with Array formula first time.. thank you for your help..much appreciated.

Comment: Same formula to test for `Y` & `N` --> `=IFERROR(IF(INDEX(Tbl_2[Transaction2_Date],MATCH(1,1/(([@ID]=Tbl_2[ID])*([@[Transaction1_Date]]<Tbl_2[Transaction2_Date])),-1))>B3,"Y","N"),"N")`

Comment: Note that this version only shows results greater than the Transaction1 Date. If the first value of ID `1000000015` is changed to `7/30/2020` that would be the closest match (smallest difference with `7/31/2020`.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
=MAP(A2:A7,B2:B7,LAMBDA(z,x,IFERROR(TAKE(SORT(FILTER(F2:F7,(E2:E7=z)*(F2:F7>x)),1,1),1,1),"NA")))
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, i'll check this option and come back. with how i go